# Get absolute screen bounds of a DOM element from a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, jsctypes

I have a firefox extension that needs to get the exact screen co-ordinates of a DOM element and passes it to a native DLL via js/c-types.

Now I have it mostly covered :

```
var gDomWindowUtils = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(nsIDOMWindowUtils);

function getScreenRect(oElem)
{
    var rc =
    {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        w : 0,
        h : 0
    };

    var o = oElement;
    while(o != null)
    {
        rc.y += o.offsetTop;
        rc.x += o.offsetLeft;
        o = o.offsetParent;
    }

    var x = {}, y = {};
    gDomWindowUtils.getScrollXY(false, x, y);
    rc.x -= x.value;
    rc.y -= y.value;

    var scale = gDomWindowUtils.screenPixelsPerCSSPixel;
    rc.x *= scale;
    rc.y *= scale;
    rc.w *= scale;
    rc.h *= scale;

    return rc;
};
```

This handles scrolling and zooming, but the values I get are relative to the browser window, and not the screen.

How do I detect the offset of the client area of the actual rendering area of the browser? 
I can even use native code (Win32) via js/ctypes so I tried to see if I could use FindWindow() / GetWindowRect() to get it, but the whole of firefox is a single HWND, the controls are all not native windows.

So one idea I have is, since the UI of firefox is an XUL document, I should be able to get the menubar, tab bar etc etc and find the browser areas absolute offset. But, I have no clue how to access the XUL tree that defines the browser UI.

Can someone give me a pointer?

[Edit]
Ignore rc.w and rc.h being undefined in the above code , it is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mostly got it already but I would recommend using [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead of `offsetLeft/offsetTop`:

```js
var rect = oElement.getBoundingClientRect();
var rc = {
  x: rect.left,
  y: rect.top,
  w: rect.width,
  h: rect.height
};
```

`getBoundingClientRect()` considers scrolling so that you no longer need to add it. You get the coordinates relative to screen using [`window.mozInnerScreenX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/mozInnerScreenX) and [`window.mozInnerScreenY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/mozInnerScreenY):

```js
rc.x += window.mozInnerScreenX;
rc.y += window.mozInnerScreenY;
```

And after that you multiply the values with `screenPixelsPerCSSPixel`. That should give you proper screen coordinates.

Comment: Now, the link is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 1):

I will add one more "trick" that helped me with a similar problem.

Whenever my code receives a mousemove event, I capture the mouse-cursor positions in ALL the coordinates that event provides, which includes at least "screen", "client" and "pageXY" coordinates.  Then for any OTHER purpose I can compute the difference between these coordinates simply by subtracting the appropriate two of those.

In your case, you'd probably compute an offset like this:

```
deltaX = event.screenX - event.clientX;
deltaY = event.screenY - event.clientY;
```

or

```
offsetX = event.screenX - event.pageX;
offsetY = event.screenY - event.pageY;
```

Then just add deltaX and deltaY or offsetX and offsetY to those coordinates to get screen coordinates.